# IGP of Ivy bridge can't be found by OpenCL SDK

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel

I have set up a IvyBridge platform for coding OpenCL program. My system is win7 64-bit, VS2010 as developement tools. There is one i7-3770k with a nVidia GTX560 on my PC. When I queried the devices of my system, I cann't find HD4000. I have checked my system driver for HD4000 by using this webpage: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics. The report said "Current Driver Installed 8.15.10.2696". OpenCL SDK is the latest Intel SDK for OpenCL Application 2012 windows 64-bit downloaded from http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/. The following is my code and the output.

I also noticed that the device name of CPU is very strange.  By the way, I have connected the HD4000 device to a monitor since I found someone met the issue that failed to create a CL context. And now I can find HD4000 can be detected by GPU-Z tool after we connected a monitor to HD4000. So anyone can help me solve this problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cl_platform_id *platforms;
    cl_uint num_platforms;
    cl_device_id *devices_cpu, *devices_gpu;
    cl_uint num_devices;

    char dev_name[40], dev_vendor[40], dev_version[40], dev_profile[40];
    char plt_name[40], plt_vendor[40], plt_version[40], plt_profile[40];

    clGetPlatformIDs(1, NULL, &num_platforms);
    platforms = (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * num_platforms);
    clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);
    for(int i = num_platforms - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sizeof(plt_name),&plt_name,NULL);
        clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, sizeof(plt_vendor),&plt_vendor,NULL);
        clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, sizeof(plt_version),&plt_version,NULL);
        clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE, sizeof(plt_profile),&plt_profile,NULL);
        printf("\n\n\nPlatform #%d Info: \n\n", i);
        printf("Platform: %s \n", plt_name);
        printf("Vendor: %s \n", plt_vendor);
        printf("Version: %s \n", plt_version);
        printf("Profile: %s \n", plt_profile);

        clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, NULL, &num_devices);
        devices_cpu = (cl_device_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id) * num_devices);
        clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, num_devices, devices_cpu, NULL);
       for(int j = 0 ; j < num_devices; j++)
       {
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_cpu[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(dev_name), &dev_name, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_cpu[j], CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, sizeof(dev_vendor), &dev_vendor, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_cpu[j], CL_DEVICE_VERSION, sizeof(dev_version), &dev_version, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_cpu[j], CL_DEVICE_PROFILE, sizeof(dev_profile), &dev_profile, NULL);
           printf("\n\n\nCPU Device Info: \n\n");
           printf("Name: %s \n", dev_name);
           printf("Vendor: %s \n", dev_vendor);
           printf("Version: %s \n", dev_version);
           printf("Profile: %s \n", dev_profile);
       }
       clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, NULL, &num_devices);
       devices_gpu = (cl_device_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id) * num_devices);
       clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, num_devices, devices_gpu, NULL);
       for(int j = 0; j < num_devices; j++)
       {
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_gpu[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(dev_name), &dev_name, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_gpu[j], CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, sizeof(dev_vendor), &dev_vendor, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_gpu[j], CL_DEVICE_VERSION, sizeof(dev_version), &dev_version, NULL);
           clGetDeviceInfo(devices_gpu[j], CL_DEVICE_PROFILE, sizeof(dev_profile), &dev_profile, NULL);
           printf("\n\n\nGPU Device Info: \n\n");
           printf("Platform: %s \n", dev_name);
           printf("Vendor: %s \n", dev_vendor);
           printf("Version: %s \n", dev_version);
           printf("Profile: %s \n", dev_profile);
       }
       free((void*)devices_cpu);
       free((void*)devices_gpu);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> Platform #1 Info: 
> Platform: Intel(R) OpenCL 
> Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation 
> Version: OpenCL 1.1 
> Profile: FULL_PROFILE 
> CPU Device Info: 
> Name: ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌIntel(R) Corporation 
> Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation 
> Version: OpenCL 1.1 (Build 31360.31441) 
> Profile: FULL_PROFILE 
> Platform #0 Info: 
> Platform: NVIDIA CUDA 
> Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation 
> Version: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.2.1 
> Profile: FULL_PROFILE 
> GPU Device Info: 
> Platform: GeForce GTX 560 Ti 
> Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation 
> Version: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 
> Profile: FULL_PROFILE
> ```

Comment: What does GPU Caps say?    http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/  Intel list many entries on the Khronos web site for  conformant OpenCL  but  they provide no details unlike AMD. http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opencl

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL does not work on HD4000 if there is no display connected to the card. 
This is from my own testing and answers in Intel forums.

See these threads on Intel forums: [1](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/278555) [2](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/277886) [3](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/277261).

Comment: For me connecting a monitor via a displayport to dvi adapter did not work. Connecting a monitor with displayport cable worked.

Comment: I have a monitor connected to the HD4000, it works, GPU-Z sees my HD4000 and my discrete Nvidia Titan Black, but OpenCL cannot find the HD4000, and yes like the OP I have the latest Intel OpenCL SDK installed (have uninstalled and reinstalled 4 or 5 times now) and the latest driver...